# Delta hedge for derivative in Black-Scholes market

Tags: black-scholes, delta-hedging, replication

Consider a derivative in the Black-Scholes market with the price formula $\Pi_t = F(t,S_t)$. I want to find a self-financing portfolio consisting of the stock and the bank account that hedges the derivative.

The value process of the hedging portfolio is given by $ V_t = h^S_t S_t + h^B_t B_t.$ The dynamics of the value process for the hedging portfolio is now given by (according to the condition of self-financing)
$$ dV_t = h^S_t dS_t + h^B_t dB_t.$$

If we apply Itô's formula to the price process, $\Pi_t = F(t, S_t)$, we get that
$$
d\Pi_t = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(t, S_t) + \frac{\sigma^2 S_t^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial S_t^2} F(t, S_t)\right) \frac{1}{rB_t} \, dB_t + \frac{\partial}{\partial S_t} F(t, S_t) dS_t
$$
If we choose
$$
h^B_t = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(t, S_t) + \frac{\sigma^2 S_t^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial S_t^2} F(t, S_t)\right) \frac{1}{rB_t} \, ,
$$
$$
h^S_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial S_t} F(t, S_t),
$$

the dynamics of $V$ and $\Pi$ are the same. How can I simplify this so that I get
$$
h^B_t = \frac{F(t,S_t)-h^S_tS_t}{B_t} = \frac{F(t,S_t)-S_t \frac{\partial}{\partial S_t}F(t,S_t)}{B_t},
$$
$$
h^S_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial S_t} F(t, S_t),
$$

I am supposed to use that $F$ satisfies the Black-Scholes PDE. But I don't understand how $F$ satisfies the Black-Scholes PDE. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: The change in the portfolio is supposed to return the risk-free rate: $d\Pi = r\Pi dt$

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!